# 4K videos are not playing smoothly?

Tags: mpv-media-player

***I always use `mpv video player` to play all types of video formats***
In my laptop ( [dell inspiron 5559 core i3](https://www.91mobiles.com/dell-15-5559-z566303uin9-core-i3-6th-gen-4-gb-1-tb-ubuntu-laptop-price-in-india-118357) ), 4k videos of dimension 3840 x 2160 (of 30fps) were playing very smoothly with `mpv` video player yet . But today I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04, after installation complete, I again install `mpv` using the command `sudo apt install mpv`
 and 'mpv' installed successfuly but now I found that 4k videos (of 30fps) are not playing smoothly.

---

**Note :**

- I always use `mpv video player` to play all types of video formats.
- I never ever use `'vlc'` to play 4k videos or hd videos because every time `mpv` done that job very smoothly.
- may be i missed some packages for videos.
- I tried to play 4K videos with other players like (mplayer, gnome-mpv, and ubuntu default player) but no one play 4K videos smoothly.
- **4K videos were playing properly before i did reinstall .**

What is the problem ?, i am very upset to face such kind of problems ?

Comment: I find [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en-GB.html) plays HD & UHD perfectly well.

Comment: Now, I installed vlc but playing 4k video is not better than mpv.

Comment: _Now I think the solution is only reinstall ubuntu again ._

Comment: I would not do that yet. Do HD videos play OK on VLC? What about YouTube videos as a good test?

Comment: I recently check 4k video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldWvm-ZqKaY on youtube, and i found that only 4k  video also lags there . What is the problem ?

Comment: I don't think it's either of the media players. VLC plays that YT vid for me without an issue. At a guess I'd say it's possible that your video driver has become corrupted if videos played OK before.

Comment: @PaulBenson How can i reinstall video driver, so that i again watch 4K vdo as before ?

Comment: I'm not saying it is the video driver. It is just one possibility. It could also be a codec issue. When you re-installed Ubuntu, did you run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`? That's the first thing you should do after an installation.

Comment: yes I did today, but nothing new .

Comment: Guys, I cleaned my laptop fan and now laptop's performance increases and also 4k videos are playing smoothly :)

Comment: Guys, videos were not playing smoothly during charging my laptop.